# Cannot access RabbitMQ on Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am sure the answer here is something real obvious that I am missing here. I have Docker for Windows installed on a Win 10 Pro machine. The Windows machine is on the 192.168.40/24 network.

I pull and install RabbitMQ as follows:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit  --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management
```

And I can see that it is running successfully:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                                 NAMES
3cabceeade6e        rabbitmq:3-management   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes              4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15671-15672/tcp, 25672/tcp   some-rabbit
```

However I cannot telnet to either 5671 or 15672 on 127.0.0.1. I have also tried disabling the Windows firewall with no luck.

Not sure how this relates but Docker is configured with the following networking settings:

[image]

**EDIT:** The IP address information is:

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "707c66b726b25c80abfebb1712d3bb0ae588dd77c996013bb528de7ac061edd4",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "15671/tcp": null,
                "15672/tcp": null,
                "25672/tcp": null,
                "4369/tcp": null,
                "5671/tcp": null,
                "5672/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/707c66b726b2",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "6e5ba9a4596967d98def608e18c9fd925a6ce036a84cd9d616f9f35d561ce68d",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "38f30e8dcf669b9419be3a03f1f296e0bed71d970516c4a1e581d37772bd1b55",
                    "EndpointID": "6e5ba9a4596967d98def608e18c9fd925a6ce036a84cd9d616f9f35d561ce68d",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

So what have I missed here that is not enabling me to access the web management interface on http://127.0.0.1:15672? While I can see the server is running on 172.17.0.2 that is clearly not on my network.

Comment: `docker inspect 3cabceeade6e` for getting ip address of containner, then try to telnet ipaddress 15672

Comment: should be `docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit  --name some-rabbit -p port:port -p port:port rabbitmq:3-management`

Comment: Added network information. When run with -p 15672:15672 -p 5671:5671 the RMQ server fails to start.

Comment: what is error code ?

Comment: You need to map the ports

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Connection refused

Comment: @Jørgen And how do I do that .... Adding -p means the container does not start. You got a docker command line I can use? After all this is just the standard RabbitMQ container. Docker is configured for Linux containers. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally figured out my stupidity:

I was adding the ports on the **end** of the  command viz:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit  --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672
```

instead of **before** the actual name of the container etc.:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management
```